# A good way to store date-based data using python?

Tags: python, date, storage

I'm working on a little pet project and I want to store data based on date, preferably using python.

The data to be stored is basically activity logs, i.e. you did a number of activities for some duration each for some date. I expect the number of 'activities' to be in the range 0 - 100 for each date.

I want to store the data using a as close to 'standard' way as possible. I'm somewhat hesitant to what format I should use.

What's a good way to store this type of data, and how can that be done using python (third party libraries and/or services included)?

Edit: I'm fully aware that there's a ton of different ways you can accomplish this, what I'm looking for is the most appropriate way to accomplish it.

Comment: csv via the `csv` module?

Comment: why wouldnt you use a database?

Comment: @JoranBeasley, I never said I wouldn't. But please tell me why you think I should use a database instead of e.g. JSON, XML, Pickle'ing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just use sqlite3 and store it as timestamps.  this is how 90% (maybe exaggerated) of the applications you encounter (and develop) will store data that they later may need to report (with the exceptions of stuff like logfiles)

```
import sqlite3,time

db = sqlite3.connect("my_database.sql") #you can put whatever ... created if not exist
conn = db.cursor()

conn.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Activities (timestamp int, name text);")

def AddActivity(activityName):
    conn.execute("INSERT INTO Activities (timestamp,name) VALUES (?,?)",(time.time(),activityName))
    db.commit()

def GetAllActivitiesOnDate(month,day,year):
    start_time = time.mktime((year,month,day,0,0,0,0,0,0)) 
    end_time = time.mktime((year,month,day,23,59,0,0,0,0)) #use 1 for last  argument if you live somewhere with dst
    conn.execute("SELECT * FROM Activities WHERE timestamp > ? AND timestamp < ?",(start_time,end_time))
    return conn.fetchall()
```

then you would do something like

```
AddActivity("Jumping Jacks")
time.sleep(10)
AddActivity("Push Ups")

import datetime
today = datetime.datetime.now()
activities = GetAllActivitiesOnDate(today.month,today.day,today.year)
print "Found %d Entries"%len(activities)
for activity in activities:
   print "Activity %s @ %s"%(activity[1],time.strftime("%x %X",
                                                 time.gmtime(int(activity[0]))))
```

this type of storage is highly extensible and easy to query exactly how you need to ... and sqlite is included with python and has a straightforward interface and application.  it scales well and if you reach a point where it doesnt scale replacing it with a higher end DB is simple

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I'm gonna go have a closer look at sqlite3. If you don't mind me asking, why do you think I should use a database instead of e.g. JSON?

Comment: I think I put the reasons in my answer ... json works good for storing onetime settings like screensize etc ... and communication with web data systems ... also this is a fairly basic example to get you started you will probably want to create a database class to manage interactions

Comment: Maybe you did, but the more detailed answer was appreciated nonetheless! I think I'll go with a database, thanks again.

Answer (score 11):

First, you want to use [ISO 8601](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/iso-time.html) for your dates. It's a no-brainer because it's simple, sorts correctly, and unambiguous to people in any part of the world.

[image: XKCD on ISO 8601]

Second, I'd probably store the data in JSON. Depending on your approach, it should have about the same simplicity as pickle, but the data will be usable to programs in other languages. You don't have to worry about the specific representation in the file, by the way, just like you don't need to worry about the intricacies of pickle formats. Your data can be any serializable object (lists, dictionaries, etc.). Based on your described use case, you probably will not have an exceptionally large dataset. Reading or writing the stored data is much simpler with JSON or even pickle. If your program grows, it may be more complicated to work with SQL statements. (Also, JSON is more or less human readable if you need to dig into the file at any point. For me, this is a major plus when working with relatively small data sets.)

For example, I'd do something like this:

```
import json

with open('file.dat','r') as f:
  data = json.load(f)
```

Your JSON will always be readable by other software, including stuff not written in Python. Saving the data is just about as easy.

```
with open('file.dat','w') as f:
  json.dump(data, f)
```

Read up on the [JSON libraries for Python](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html); they're dead simple.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If I don't decide to go with a database I will probably use JSON in the way that you describe. I'd be interested to hear why you think JSON would be more appropriate than a database in this case?

Comment: Personally, I would choose the simpler approach of a simple file. Based on your described use case, you probably will not have an exceptionally large dataset (although if you do, you might lean towards a DB), and reading or writing the stored data is much simpler with JSON or even pickle. If your program grows, it may be more complicated to work with SQL statements. Also, JSON is more or less human readable if you need to dig into the file at any point.

Comment: Thanks, I will consider using JSON. I guess it's either that or rolling a very simple db. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) or [JSON](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) or [CSV](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to store this.

Pickle is really easy:

```
import datetime
import pickle

dt=datetime.datetime(2013,3,25)

data={dt:['item 1','item 2','item 3']}

pickle.dump(data,open('/tmp/pickle.pik','wb'))

data2=pickle.load(open('/tmp/pickle.pik','rb'))

print data2==data    # True
```

The downside is that pickle is not considered secure for shared data.

Comment: What would you say be the most appropriate one of those? And what's a good way to store it based on date, without having to write too much logic for translating dates back and forth?

Comment: pickle should be used somewhat sparingly as it evals the values when loading, this leads to some vunerabilities when dealing with client data

Comment: @JoranBeasley: I believe I stated that in the answer. Pickle is fabulous for personal data. If you are doing something commercial, use a database...